# Symfony 3 form data on edit page has null field for file upload field

Tags: php, symfony

I have a fully working file upload which works when a user creates a course. I use a service which contains the following code to upload the files and to update the form data with the image paths that need to be persisted.

```
public function handleCourseUploads($request, $formData, $originalCourse)
{

    if($formData->getImage() !== null)
    {
        $courseImagePath = $this->upload($formData->getImage(), $formData->getFrameworkID() . '/course-image/');
        $formData->setImage($courseImagePath);
    }

    foreach ($formData->getModules() as $module)
    {
        if($module->getImageLink() !== null)
        {
            $moduleImage = $this->upload($module->getImageLink(),  $formData->getFrameworkID() . '/' . $module->getTitle() . '/');
            $module->setImageLink($moduleImage);
        }

        foreach ($module->getDownload() as $download)
        {
            if($download->getDownloadLink() !== null)
            {
                $downloadItem = $this->upload($download->getDownloadLink(), $formData->getFrameworkID() . '/' . $module->getTitle() . '/downloads/');
                $download->setDownloadLink($downloadItem);
            }
        }
    }

    return $formData;
}
```

When I use the same function when the edit page is submitted it says that null cannot be inserted. The formdata shows the "image link" as null which is obviously the problem. But how do I get around this?

Comment: if formdata has image link null, I see you're doing the check for not null before uploading!! I did not understand why would be the error saying null cannot be inserted? You don't just insert nulls!!

On edit page if you are not making any changes in already uploaded image then you do not need to insert/upload anything. Just do not change existing items.